# howto import c library (.dll / .so) in c# (mono)

Tags: c#, c, dll, mono, native

so i tried the tutorial from
http://www.huronbox.com/~james/techdemos/cs-callback.html

like some others i found but i am getting the same error over and over

when it comes to access a function from the imported library
i get the dllNotFoundException

anyone can help?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

Please post more details: fragment of code and name of the library file would be very useful.
I had similar problem when I tried to specify file path using slashes instead of (double) backslashes (windows convention). Next thing: remember that your program looks for the library file in the same directory where the exe is (if you don't specify the path explicitly).

Comment: you can find 1:1 code if you follow the link, the .so or .dll file is in the same folder as the programm.

Comment: ok i found out that even if you have the dll´s in the same directory you have to use absolute path syntax then it works